# Application not loading when using webswing

Tags: webswing

I am trying to migrate from webswing 2.4 to 20.1.3.
In webswing.log the  Webswing 20.1.3 initialization is done successfully.
But when I am trying to access the application its not loading.
I am seeing the following line in localhost-access.log

"GET /{APP_CONTEXT}/javascript/nls/en-US/select.json HTTP/1.1" 404

Answer (score 0):

The 404 error is not a problem. Webswing tries to load this select.json file to load available languages. If the file is not present then it ends up with 404.

If you application doesn't start there must be an error in your webswing.log file.